# Encapsulating a ajax call in a deferred object and allow an abort

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to create a global ajax call that takes care of a some global functionality, for example:

json

```
{
  Data : { /* some object returned */ },
  RedirectTo: "",   // for example: "/Account/Login"
  ErrorMessage: "", // for example: "You have been logged out do to inactivity.
}
```

jquery

```
(function (global, $, undefined)
{
  global = global || {};

  global.ajax = function(settings)
  {
    var timeoutResult = {
      Data: null,
      RedirectTo: null,
      ErrorMessage: "Your request could not be completed, please try again.";
    }

    var customResult;
    var jqXHR;
    var $deferred = $.Deferred(function()
    {
      var ajaxSettings = $.extend({
          statusCode: {
            408: function()
            {
              customResult = timeoutResult; 
            },
          },
        }, settings);


      var self = this;
      jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxSettings )
        .always(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (jsonResult.RedirectTo
              && jsonResult.RedirecTo !== null)
          {
            window.location = jsonResult.RedirectTo;
          }
        })
        .fail(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (/* some logic to bubble up fail() */)
          {
            self.reject(jsonResult);
          }
        })
        .done(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (/* some logic to bubble up done() */)
          {
            self.resolve(jsonResult);
          }
        });
    };

    return ???;

  };
}(window.global, jQuery));
```

Now the issue is I want users to be able to `.abort()`, `.done()`, and `.fail()` but I don't want them to attach the deferred calls directly to the `jqXHR` but if I don't then they can't call `abort()`.

I could return an object like:

```
{
  jqXHR: jqXHR,
  deferred: self
}
```

But then it's not intuitive.

> Reason?

I need to be in control of which `done()` and `fail()` events/methods bubbles up to the developers code.  If the user is logged out, I'm going to redirect them immediately.  Other developers code doesn't need to be executed and shouldn't really execute.

> How will request be aborted ?

A developer would want to be able to:

```
jqXHR.abort();
```

for whatever the reason.

Comment: _"Now the issue is I want users to be able to .abort(), .done(), and .fail() but I don't want them to attach the deferred calls directly to the jqXHR"_ ? Reason ? How will request be aborted ? At `return ???` , `return jqXHR` ? Whys is `self` defined within `var $deferred = $.Deferred(function()` ? That would expect `return $deferred.promise()` at `return ???` ?

Comment: Is requirement for `js` at OP to be called at every `$.ajax()` call ? Could probably be achieved without creating a new `$.Deferred()` object for each call , utilizing `.always()` , ajax events ?

Comment: Tried `$.ajaxSetup()` ?

Comment: Unless you know of a away to prevent any other deferred method to be called in an `always()` then I don't have control over other attached deferred calls.   `$.ajaxSetup()` is the worse method in all of jQuery and nobody should ever recommend it or use it.

Comment: Not certain interpret _"Unless you know of a away to prevent any other deferred method to be called in an always()"_ correctly ? Though,  could "chain", call, return `.done()` or `.fail()` from within `.always()` instead of outside of `.always()` ; where `.always()` should be called for both "resolved" or "rejected" `jqXHR` promise object . _"$.ajaxSetup() is the worse method in all of jQuery and nobody should ever recommend it or use it."_ reason ,  description ?

Comment: `.ajaxSetup()` is a global settings, using it means you can easily break other frameworks that expect `.ajax()` to behave in the default way.

Comment: If return `$deferred.promise()` , `global.ajax.reject("reason")` could be called to "abort" , or "reject" `$.deferred`

Comment: _".ajaxSetup() is a global settings, using it means you can easily break other frameworks that expect .ajax() to behave in the default way."_ . Yes, interpreted Question as this to be expected result, e.g.; handle "abort" or returned result at `.always()` differently ? Could still "chain", return "expected" `$.ajax()` results at `$.ajaxSetup()` ? `$.ajaxSetup()` aside, tried implementing both chaining `.done()` , `.fail()` at `.always()` ? Though, utilizing `.done()` , the returned jQuery promise object could not , generally, be changed ; would continue to return same response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have known in a Javascript world I can just extend objects as needed:

```
global.ajax = function(settings)
  {
    var timeoutResult = {
      Data: null,
      RedirectTo: null,
      ErrorMessage: "Your request could not be completed, please try again.";
    }

    var customResult;
    var jqXHR;
    var $deferred = $.Deferred(function()
    {
      var self = this;

      var ajaxSettings = $.extend({
          statusCode: {
            408: function()
            {
              customResult = timeoutResult; 
            },
          },
        }, settings);


      jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxSettings )
        .always(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (jsonResult.RedirectTo
              && jsonResult.RedirecTo !== null)
          {
            window.location = jsonResult.RedirectTo;
          }
        })
        .fail(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (/* some logic to bubble up fail() */)
          {
            self.reject(jsonResult);
          }
        })
        .done(function(jsonResult)
        {
          if (customResult) jsonResult = customResult;
          if (/* some logic to bubble up done() */)
          {
            self.resolve(jsonResult);
          }
        });

      // add the abort method... 
      self.abort = jqXHR.abort;

    };
  };

return $deferred;
```

Comment: `$deferred` - unnecessary; `customResult` - unnecessary; `jqXHR` - unnecessary; `statusCode: ... 408` - unnecessary;`$.extend()` - unnecessary. Summary - whole exercise is unnecessary. All you need is a chained `.then()` with a success handler that tests the presence of `result.RedirectTo`, ie `if(result.RedirectTo) window.redirect = result; else return result`.

Comment: Doing something special for a 408 is not necessary because a 408 is an error, so will go down the error path of the promise chain. The defaults `Data: null` and `RedirectTo: null` are therefore redundant as is the error message "Your request could not be completed, please try again.", which is not as meaningful as the naturally occurring `textStatus` made available to an error handler.

Comment: Well without a good example, your comment are... unnecessary.  You haven't shown how to return an object that can `abort()` the ajax call.  You are severely wrong about about giving an end user textStatus, [there](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/08/avoid-being-embarrassed-by-your-error-messages.php) are [so](http://uxmag.com/articles/are-you-saying-no-when-you-could-be-saying-yes-in-your-web-forms) many articles about [giving the user a good experience with error messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742471.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I can't give this any more time.